# use variable with ajax scope - closure? callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having some difficulty using a variable within an `ajax()` function. I know it is because the variable is not in the scope of the `ajax()` call but not sure how to fix this. I've read a bit about closures and callbacks for things like this but not really sure how to actually apply that to my code.

Code summary: on `click()` I get `user_notes` via ajax, and on that success I pop up a dialog box displaying the `user_notes` (all this works so far). Where it breaks down is when I then try and do another ajax call when the "Save" button is pressed. In that second ajax call `user_notes` is undefined within that scope.

How can I use `user_notes` within that second ajax call?

```
 $(".editSaved").click(function() {
            save_id = $(this).attr('id');
            var user_notes;

            //GET USER NOTES
            $.ajax ({
                url:"journal-util.php",
                data:"q=0&f=user_notes&save_id="+save_id,
                success: function(user_notes){

                    //BUILD SAVE DIALOG
                    div="<div><textarea rows=15 cols=27 id='RowSave'>"+user_notes+"</textarea></div>";
//AT THIS POINT USER_NOTES HAS A VALUE
                    success="<div>Updated!</div>";
                    $(div).dialog({ 
                        buttons: { 
                            "Save": function() { 
                                var that = this;
                                var un = user_notes; //tried this, didn't work
                                $.ajax ({
                                    url:"journal-util.php",
                                    data:"q=0&f=update&user_notes="+un, //un is empty
                                    success: function(result){
                                        alert(result);
                                        $(that).dialog("close");
                                        //$(success).dialog();
                                    }
                                })
                            },
                            "Cancel": function() { 
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            } 
                        },
                        modal: true,
                        title: 'Delete',
                        resizable: false
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Is `un` empty at the point where you say `var un = user_notes;`? (Also, what is the `var user_notes` for, declared right near the top?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution

```
un = $('#RowSave').val();
```

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: actually @amgates you've nailed what the problem actually was (I figured it out soon after asking). user_notes was working just fine within the new ajax call - I was just calling an old value. Your code above should be var un = $('#RowSave').val()

Answer (score 2):

### Why doesn't work

The problem why your code is not working is that when your second AJAX success callback function is fired, the value `user_notes` holds might have already be altered or reset. To make it work, you need to capture the **value** of `user_notes` in that scope.

### Solution

Replace your "Save" callback with a closure to hold the `user_notes` value within that scope.

```
"Save": function (un) {
          return function() {
                    var that = this;
                    $.ajax ({
                        url:"journal-util.php",
                        data:"q=0&f=update&user_notes="+un, 
                        success: function(result){
                            alert(result);
                            $(that).dialog("close");
                            //$(success).dialog();
                        }
                    });
                };
          } (user_notes),
```

Comment: doesn't work. at the point you mention above user_notes already has a defined value. When I use it in the DIV a few lines down it has the right value.

Comment: @steven: The parameter in `success: function(user_notes)` is set automatically by jQuery (and will be the ajax response data).

Comment: A, mistake. user_notes is just the `data` of an Ajax callback. I will update the post soon.

Comment: @themerlinproject updated the post, see if it works. Sorry for the misunderstanding before.

Answer (score 0):

You're aware that you have two declarations of  `user_notes`? Once using var in the inside the click method and again as a parameter in the first ajax. The first one remains undefined, the second is only defined if the success method is called with a defined parameter.

Careful about redefining a name in nested scopes, it's confusing.

Change that first, then if the value of parameter to the success method is what you want, you should explicitly save it to a variable.

(Personally I would not write that nested code. I'd probably use an object with a variable to store the data and a `that=this`-reference and have thin inline function wrappers on the ajax success and failures that just call object member methods. I like to avoid deep nesting of scopes, and to avid having to scroll horizontally ;)